# Уменьшение всего body под размер страницы

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть html страница, где почти все объекты в абсолютной позиции и с заданными left: и top: в style. Вопрос такой. Страница, естественно, не адаптивная(не сжимается под размеры нужного экрана). И при маленьком экране попросту становится похожей на приближение лупой. Вопрос в том, есть ли другие способы сделать подгонку страницы под размеры браузера кроме как через изменение всех стилей на vw vh и max-width. (грубо говоря, через @media сделать уменьшение всего body принудительно под размеры экрана, или что то в таком духе.) Очень прошу вашей помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Всё зависит от того используете ли вы цирину и высоту элементов в пикселях или в процентах

Comment: Забыл упомянуть. Речь о пикселях. Почти все стили указаны в left: N px; top: N px;

Comment: Ну не знаю, сделать адаптивную страницу которая сделала с помошью абсолютной позиции и с заданными left и top это очень сложно, даже используя @media. Легче будет переписать страницу с нуля